# How to trigger web extension in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox add on implemented as a web extension.

When I install the app on firefox for android, there is no button to trigger the action for the app - this is because [browser actions are not supported on Firefox for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction)

So, next I looked into adding a context menu item, to allow the user to trigger the extension that way. [However, unfortunately the context menu API is not supported in Firefox for android either](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus).

So - what options do I have with regards to adding some sort of UI so that the user can trigger my web extension?

Comment: I've not researched this area, so not a full answer: You always have the option of inserting a UI element directly into each page. It is not an option I like (possible significant burden to all pages, UI compatibility issues with random pages, etc.), but it does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only answers to this at the current time are:

i) to use [pageActions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction) which weren't really designed for this purpose (they are supposed to be for things which are only applicable to certain pages.

ii) as in @Makyen comment above to add something to the dom which is clickable